# Using matplotlib to draw color bar with distinguishable and uncontinues colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

The color bar in the figure below is drawn in matlab. I am wondering if it is possible to draw the similar color bar in python/matplotlib? I need the **un-smoothing** color changes in the color bar, so that the values 0-5 will be represented in very **distinguishable and uncontinuous** coulors. If possible, could you please give me an example? Thanks~

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ListedColormap](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap) and [BoundaryNorm](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot
data = np.floor(np.random.random((10,10)) * 6)
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['w', 'b', 'g', 'y', '#ff8c00', 'r'])
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], cmap.N)
pyplot.imshow(data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='none')
pyplot.colorbar()
pyplot.show()
```

Some examples of using ListedColormap: [colorbars](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/colorbar_only.html?highlight=listedcolormap), [multicolored lines](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html?highlight=listedcolormap).