# Controlling the Range of a Color Matrix Plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to make a matrix plot like the image below in matplotlib. I can make this a plot like this with this code:

```
m = numpy.random.rand(100,100)
matplotlib.pyplot.matshow(m)
```

How can I control the color scale, i.e. set the values corresponding to the "min" and "max" colors?

[image]

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707676/defining-a-discrete-colormap-for-imshow-in-matplotlib) seems give a good way to specify not only the color bar but the bounds.

Comment: @tcaswell My mistake, fixed

Comment: @tcaswell Can they ever? ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `matshow` docs indicate that the options are mostly just passed to `imshow` ([docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)).  Imshow takes arguments `vmin` and `vmax` that determine the min and max colors as you desire.  Let's check out an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
A = np.arange(0,100).reshape(10,10)
plt.matshow(A)                        # defaults
plt.matshow(A, vmin=0, vmax=99)       # same
plt.matshow(A, vmin=10, vmax=90)      # top/bottom rows get min/max colors, respectively
```

### Aside:

May I also recommend changing the colormap?  eg. `cmap='hot'`.  Though it is the default (why?), the `'jet'` colormap is [almost never the best choice](http://www.jwave.vt.edu/~rkriz/Projects/create_color_table/color_07.pdf).

```
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)+5
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins=40, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: output of the examle code with cmap='hot']