# Matplotlib: Custom colormap with three colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to pass a colormap to a `matplotlib.imshow` to plot a NxN array where each cell can only take the values -1,0 and 1.
I would like my colormap to map exactly one color (in hex code) to each value.

I just have no idea how to define a custom colormap which is not a gradation between two colors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution to a very similar question was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707676/defining-a-discrete-colormap-for-imshow-in-matplotlib). In summary ,

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(list-of-colours)
```

is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer to my question, as fernando suggested:

```
import matplotlib
colorsList = [(tuple rgb color 1),(tuple rgb color 2),(tuple rgb color 3)]
CustomCmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colorsList)
```