# Custom Colormap using Matplotlib.image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib.image.imsave('file.png',file,cmap=cmap)` to save a `.png` of a 2d Numpy array where the array can only have values of 0, 1 or 10.  I would like 0 to be white, 1 to be green and 10 to be red.  I saw something similar at this question:  [Matplotlib: Custom colormap with three colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952963/matplotlib-custom-colormap-with-three-colors) .  The problem is that `imsave` does not take norm as an argument but using `pyplot` is too slow for my application.  Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Both great answers, I appreciate the feedback.  With my specific application, using LinearSgmentedColormap.from_list had significant performance benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input array consisting of values `[0,1,10]` is not really an image array. Image arrays would go from `0` to `255` or from `0.` to `1.`.

#### a. using a `LinearSegmentedColormap`

An idea can be to normalize your array `im` to 1.: `im = im/im.max()`. It is then possible to create a colormap with the values
`0 -> white, 0.1 -> green, 1 -> red` using `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list`.

```
import matplotlib.image
import numpy as np

im = np.random.choice([0,1,10], size=(90, 90), p=[0.5,0.3,0.2])

im2 = im/10.
clist = [(0,"white"), (1./10.,"green"), (1, "red")]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("name", clist)
matplotlib.image.imsave(__file__+'.png', im, cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

The corresponding pyplot plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(im, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar(ticks=[0,1,10])
plt.show()
```

would look like this

[image]

#### b. using a `ListedColormap`

A `ListedColormap` can be used to generate a colormap of the three colors white, green and red. In this colormap the colors are equally spaced, so one needs to map the image array to equally spaced values as well. This can be done using `np.unique(im,return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(im.shape)`, which returns an array containing only the values `[0,1,2]`. We again need to normalize to 1.

```
im = np.random.choice([0,1,10], size=(90, 90), p=[0.5,0.3,0.2])

im2 = np.unique(im,return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(im.shape)
im3 = im2/float(im2.max())

clist = ["white", "green","red"]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(clist)
matplotlib.image.imsave(__file__+'2.png',im3, cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

While the output image looks exactly the same as above, the corresponding matplotlib plot would have a different colorbar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(im2, cmap=cmap)
cb = plt.colorbar(ticks=[0,1,2])
cb.ax.set_yticklabels([0,1,10])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I really like your matplotlib-based answers here on SO! Your approach has the advantage of beeing completely based on matplotlib allowing labels and (discrete) colormaps if needed!

Answer (score 2):

Just build a `(N, M, 3)` array and treat it as image-pixels in RGB-mode.
Then it's enough to map your 3 unique values to those 3 colors.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imsave

raw = np.random.choice((0,1,10), size=(500, 500))
img = np.empty((raw.shape[0], raw.shape[1], 3))

img[raw == 0] = (255, 255, 255)  # RGB -> white
img[raw == 1] = (0,255,0)        #        green
img[raw == 10] = (255,0,0)       #        red

imsave('image.png', img)
```

[image]

I'm using scipy's `imsave` here, but the matplotlib one probably works the same.