# Discrete pyplot scatter colobar

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am creating a scatterplot with a colorbar

```
plt.scatter(X, Y, c=Z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

where X and Y are float arrays and Z is an integer array. 
Even though Z is an integer array (here 1-14), the colorbar displays floats. 
[image]

How can I display a discrete colorbar 1-14?

I found something attempting to answer a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777066/matplotlib-discrete-colorbar), but I don't understand the answer (containing some complications to make 0 be gray) well enough to apply it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14777392/5067311) to your linked question. If you discretize your colourmap before calling `scatter`, it will automatically work as you want it to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

n = 14
X = np.random.rand(20)
Y = np.random.rand(20)
Z = np.random.randint(low=0,high=n,size=X.shape)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X,Y,c=Z,cmap=cm.hot)
plt.colorbar()

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X,Y,c=Z,cmap=cm.get_cmap('hot',n))
plt.colorbar()
```

Results for comparison:

[image: smooth][image: discretized]

Note that the default colourmap is `jet`. But only until `viridis` kicks in [starting from version 2.0](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colormap) as the new (and wonderful) default.

If what's bothering you is that the numbers are floating-point on the colourbar, you can set manual `ticks` in it, irrespective of the discretization of colours:

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X,Y,c=Z,cmap=cm.jet)
plt.colorbar(ticks=np.unique(Z))
#or
#plt.colorbar(ticks=range(Z.min(),Z.max()+1))
```

Result:

[image: integer ticks]

Note that since I used a few random-generated points, not every number is present in `Z`, so `unique` might not be the best approach (see the missing ticks in the above figure). This is why I also added a solution based on `min/max`. You can tailor the limits to your needs depending on your actual application.

Comment: This does seem to be what I'm looking for, however my attempt at         `plt.scatter(X, Y, c = Z, cmap=cm.get_cmap('RdPu',n), s=100, vmin=np.min(Z), vmax=np.max(Z))` yields the error `NameError: name 'cm' is not defined`, even with `import matplotlib.cm as cm`

Comment: @astromonerd that is most unusual. Have you tried turning it off an on again?:) Are you using ipython or just a regular python script? The above code works fine for me in the former. Anyway, if the `import` dosn't throw any error, then you shouldn't get that error.

Comment: @astromonerd Oh, and I believe the default behaviour of `scatter` is to use `vmin=np.min(c),vmax=np.max(c)`, so you can save yourself some typing with that:)

Comment: I mis-tagged (and corrected) that I am using ipython-notebook (v 3.0.0)

Comment: I restarted the kernel into which I was importing the header and now it works. Turning it off and on again for the win.

Comment: @astromonerd glad to hear it, thanks for the feedback:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my discrete colorbar for land use type, it seems like your work,because the Z value is also an interger array from 1-14.

#### My method

> creat the colormap and colorbar label manually learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707676/defining-a-discrete-colormap-for-imshow-in-matplotlib)

#### My Code

```
cMap = ListedColormap(['white', '#8dd3c7','#ffffb3','#bebada',  \               
                       '#b2182b','#80b1d3','#fdb462','#b3de69','#6a3d9a',\
                       '#b2df8a', '#1f78b4', '#ccebc5','#ffed6f'])

## If you want to use the colormap from plt.cm..., you can use(take 'jet' for example) 
cMap = plt.cm.get_cmap("jet",lut=13)  

### here you can change your data in    
lulc = plt.pcolormesh(lulc,cmap = cMap,alpha = 0.7)   

z_range = np.linspace(1,14,14)
list = z_range.astype('S10')

k = -0.05
for i in range(0,13,1):
    k = k + 1/13.0
   ax.annotate(list[i],xycoords='axes fraction',xy=(1.12,k),fontsize = 14, \
               fontstyle = 'italic',zorder =3)

cbar = plt.colorbar(lulc,ticks = [ ])
for label in cbar.ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()[::-1]:
    label.set_visible(False)
```

#### My result

[image]
<sub>(source: [tietuku.com](http://i4.tietuku.com/7a7c522b918862ba.png))</sub>

Wish it can help!