# How to replicate the pseudo 3D plot of gnuplot in matplotlib, for secondary structure assignment of a protein over time?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gnuplot

I'm trying to replicate a plot, created in gnuplot, using matplotlib. The type of plot used by gnuplot (below) is called a pseudo 3D plot.

[image: Secondary structure assignment of protein over time]

What this is showing is secondary structure assignment for each residue of a peptide/protein over time. So, at each time step (column) you're seeing the secondary structure assignment for a single peptide. For each residue (row) you're seeing how that residue's secondary structure assignment changes over time.

I want to adapt this type of plot to matplotlib. What would be an appropriate type of plot in matplotlib to do this?

The most rudimentry solution I could think of was to simply use patches to draw rectangles at the correct coordinates, but I was hoping to use an existing matplotlib plot type that's more flexible and robust to customisation.

The data is structured like so:

```
data = [[x1, y1, z11], [x1, y2, z12], [x1, y3, z13], ..., [xn, ym, znm]]
```

Where n is the total number of time steps and m is the total number of residues. Z values are categorical data for secondary structure assignment at the xy coordinates.

Some actual data you could use to test this where there is a peptide with three residues over three time steps:

```
data = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [2, 1, 6], [2, 2, 6], [2, 3, 6], [3, 1, 6], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0]]
```

Comment: You can use an `imshow` or a `pcolormesh` plot. Both expect 2D arrays as input, hence you need to look into numpy and reshape your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obtain the following graph, using inspiration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9708079/8069403) and this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jakevdp/8a992f606899ac24b711):

[image: pcolor with categorical data]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from matplotlib import colors

data = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 2], [1, 3, 0], [2, 1, 6], [2, 2, 6], [2, 3, 6], [3, 1, 6], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0]]


# format the data into an array, zero as default
x_max = max( u[0] for u in data ) + 1
y_max = max( u[1] for u in data ) + 1
z_max = max( u[2] for u in data ) + 1

z = np.zeros((x_max, y_max))
for u in data:
    z[u[0], u[1]] = u[2]

# Define the x and y range:
x = range(x_max + 1)
y = range(y_max + 1)

# Colormap with discrete values and corresponding labels:
labels = ['random', 'helix', 'coil', 'pi', 'beta', 'turn', 'bridge']
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['white', 'blue', 'green', 'magenta', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow'])
bounds = range(cmap.N+1)
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

plt.pcolor(x, y, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

formatlabels = plt.FixedFormatter( labels )
plt.colorbar(cmap=cmap, norm=norm, boundaries=bounds, ticks=bounds,
             format=formatlabels, drawedges=True);
```