# Custom color scales on heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to get a custom color scale for the heatmap that I am going to generate for the data similar to below one:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],"y": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], "res":[0,5,5,10,5,15,20]})
```

The color condition would be:

Grey: for res <= 0, Yellow: for res >0, Orange: for res >5, Red: for res >10 etc.

I have tried seaborn heatmap but not able to set the conditioned custom color scale.
Any clue would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind to show us some code?

Comment: You can build one following this [link](https://plot.ly/python/v3/colorscales/)

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707676/defining-a-discrete-colormap-for-imshow-in-matplotlib) about how to build a colormap with associated boundarynorm. The post is for 2 colors, more colors just means adding to the list of colors and of boundaries.

Answer (score -1):

since you tagged plotly, you can find an example on how to create a custom colorscale here https://plot.ly/python/colorscales/#constructing-a-discrete-or-discontinuous-color-scale - but reading through the whole page is useful (and the heatmap tutorial is here https://plot.ly/python/heatmaps/).

Comment: how about
go.Heatmap(
    z=matrix,
    colorscale=[
        [0, "#000000"],
        [1, "#FF0000"],
    ],
)