# How do I make a custom colorbar for a matplotlib imshow plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have tried the method from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707676/defining-a-discrete-colormap-for-imshow-in-matplotlib) but it does not work, because the shape of my array is 3D, whereas the shape they use is 2D.

I begin with a 3-dimensional array

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ins = np.load('ins.npy')
ex = ins[1]
ex.shape
# (60,60,1)
```

Now I plot the image.

```
ax = plt.gca()
im = ax.imshow(ex)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
```

I've searched for hours and, though this seems very simple, I haven't been able to find a way to create my own colorbar. I would like to use a colorscheme similar to the one employed by the weather service. The ticks would be:

```
ticks = [20,35,45,55,65,75]
```

I've tried doing:

```
x = [20,35,45,55,65,75]
colors = ["#eaa941", "#efef39", "#53a447", "#3b387f", "#48a2ba"]
cmap= mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
cmap.set_under("crimson")
cmap.set_over("w")
norm= mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=-70)   

im = ax.contourf(x,x,ex, levels=[20,35,45,55,65,75],extend='both',cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
```

But no luck.

Comment: The issue is with the way you have created the the `cotourf`: `x,x,ex` do not seem to be correctly defined. The duplicate works fine, as it is implemented the same way with the examples shown at [matplotlib: `matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf.html)

Comment: In response to _I have tried the method from this question but it does not work_. Here's a simple example directly from the docs, which then uses the duplicate to add a colorbar. `x = np.arange(0, 100); y = x.reshape(-1, 1); h = x * y; cs = plt.contourf(h, levels=[20,35,45,55,65,75], colors=["#eaa941", "#efef39", "#53a447", "#3b387f", "#48a2ba"], extend='both'); plt.colorbar(cs, ticks=bounds)`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Oh, wow. It works now. Huh. Yea I think I was missing the bounds argument and incorrectly pointing to ```x```. Gosh, that gave me such a headache! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Actually, I've found the problem. I have to transform an array from ```(1, 3600)``` to the shape ```(60,60,1)```, but the contourf function only takes 2D fields. If I simply reshape my array into ```(60,60)``` the image is lost. I think it's folded in wrong or... I'm not sure

Comment: I think how to correctly shape the arrays, might be a different question. You should create a new question, but be sure to provide a sufficient example of your data, that someone can answer the question, and show what you've tried.