# Matplotlib create a Cityscapes_Pallette_Map

Tags: matplotlib, colormap

I would like to create a Cityscapes_Palette_Map as a "colormap" for my semantic segmentation output.

The definition of color for each pixel value range from 0 to 22 is as shown in the [link](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.11/tuto_D_create_semantic_tags/).

I see a lot of example of creating a "continuous" cmap but what I need is "discrete" cmap to map an int pixel value (class) to a specific color. I wonder if anyone can point me to the right reference to solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

Matplotlib still [doesn't have an easy way to map integers to colors](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/21786).
Usually, the most straightforward way is to simply apply the mapping outside of matplotlib and then pass the color values to matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10
x = np.random.rand(n)
y = np.random.rand(n)
color_as_integer = np.random.randint(3, size=n)

colormap = {
    0  : np.array([  0,   0,   0, 255]),     # unlabelled
    1  : np.array([ 70,  70,  70, 255]),     # building
    2  : np.array([100,  40,  40, 255]),     # fence
}

# matplotlib works with rbga values in the range 0-1
colormap = {k : v / 255. for k, v in colormap.items()}

color_as_rgb = np.array([colormap[ii] for ii in color_as_integer])

plt.scatter(x, y, s=100, c=color_as_rgb)
plt.show()
```

You can then use proxy artists to create a legend as outlined [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#proxy-legend-handles).

The alternative is to use a combination of ListedColormap and BoundaryNorm to map integers to colors, as outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9708079/2912349).

In that case, you can also get a colorbar as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28730546/2912349) (although making a proper legend is probably better in your case).