# Create a discrete colorbar for integer values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar, discrete

I have a question and hope someone can help me out with this one:

I would like to create a colorbar like in the picture below (the picture was created in PowerPoint , so code behind it). The idea is that I would like to display in a plot whether certain files in a folder are not available, available once or available several times.

I have already seen some code snippets here on stackoverflow, but unfortunatly I do not get it...

Has anyone an idea how to create that?

Thank you all in advance!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib discrete colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777066/matplotlib-discrete-colorbar)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining a discrete colormap for imshow in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707676/defining-a-discrete-colormap-for-imshow-in-matplotlib)